# Mongodb was hacked, how to create new user and is there a way to recover?

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to access an old mongodb server that I havnt used for weeks. But RoboMongo and 3TStudio were both rejected, so I logged on with putty and found this:

```
> show dbs;
WRITE_ME  0.000GB
admin     0.000GB
local     0.000GB
thaihome  0.000GB
```

This pretty much looks like we were hacked, which is really strange cause the mongodb password were very long and full of numbers/letters/characters etc..  So we have no idea how they got in.

I do have backups of everything, so no harm done (other than hurt pride hehe).

Question:  Right now there is nothing in admin, so how so I log on to the database from e.g. Robomongo or Studio3T?  How can you create a user so you can login again?

Question2:  Does debian/ubuntu have a undelete command or otherway to recover deleted data?  (if not I will restore from backup but it will take time)

Comment: have you checked WRITE_ME ? Atleast have a look and try to find out how mush they have asked for ransom

Comment: I did hehe - they want 1 Bitcoin - I have heard a from a lot of people who paid and they still didn't get the data back. Paying a "kidnapper" is never an option for me. I would rather pay 100 Bitcoin to have him "taken care of" hehehe :-D

Comment: hahaha good choice :P

Comment: @torbenrudgaard Sorry to hear about that, but one learns form their own mistakes. 3 points to make : First, never use Robomongo/Studio3T in Production, Secondly, never ever push your credentials to Github or other VCS, Thirdly, restrict admin access (network level) to your instance (db server).

Comment: @shikharbansal ahhhh.... thats what we did - thats where they got the password.  Damn it :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i will suggest you to **change the password** of your `mongodb` server(i guess you would have done that by now).

Second, i will suggest that you **change mongodb port** from `default(27017)` to some other port. Its easiest to hack when your mongodb server is hosted on default port 27017. Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.port) link to change port.

Next, i will suggest that you **give access to only certain IPs**, so that only those IPs can access your db, thus reducing the chance of getting hacked. One way to do that is to `bind mongodb` with `127.0.0.1` that is only local connections, and no one else in the world gets access to your db.

You can edit your `mongodb configuration file` to bind IP and change port.

Read [MongoDB configuration options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) to get detailed information on how to change port and bind IP.

it will be something like this:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1 // if you want to provide multiple do this : [127.0.0.1,X.X.X.X]
   port: 27017 // change this to some other port : 12345
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

Next, you can create new admin users to get access to your db. use `createRole` to create new role based users. Its best to have role based authentication in your mongodb server.

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "mongostatRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "serverStatus" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Read [How to Manage users and Roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) for detailed explanation and resources.

At last, there are few Blogs/Links which explains how to secure DB. i think you should read them and make your DB secure and hack proof.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-secure-mongodb-nosql-production-database/

Comment: Ravi Shankar, You have so much spark in your answer that I think that your black goggles are made compulsory by the Government.

Comment: Hahaha @shikharbansal you are right.  I could use a few Ravi's to protect our servers for sure :-D   Thanks for a GREAT answer Ravi!!!

Comment: @RaviShankar thanks a lot :)  One quick question, I got a mongodb running locally here with no access to outside, and I need to move it to our Ocean droplet server (mongodb server). I read the mongo doc about mongodump/mongorestore but its SUPER technical and they write way too much stuff that I dont need to know and totally forget a simple example command for us normal people.  I managed to dump it into a folder.  Now I have to restore: `mongorestore --port 27117 --archive` but where should I put the files on the new server? And dont I need a path to do that?

Comment: Never mind heheh found a good guide on Ocean... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-a-mongodb-database-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Generally, dump is created in default `dump/` folder unless specified. So when you do mongorestore, you have to provide that location like this: `mongorestore --port 27117 <path to the backup>`
 Here is another good tutorial from official mongodb docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/

Comment: PS. Change the port again from 27117 to something else,  people might find out your mongodb port from here. :p :D

Answer (score 0):

**Adding to the first answer:**

If you want to bind multiple IP addresses through `bindip` then you need to configure the IP addresses to the server's network interface otherwise MongoDB won't let you bind multiple IP addresses.

[Here is more](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cannot-bind-mongodb-to-vms-public-ip/6458/2)